# Generic Class override and Problems for others Grid

Tags: magento2, filter

Actually i had override the generic class to filter the orders for sales order grid.

`<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" type="VendorName\ModuleName\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"/>`

It create problem for me in others grid like `invoice grid` , `Shipment grid` etc

My code is there for filter order

```
 protected function searchResultToOutput(SearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $arrItems = [];
        $arrItems['items'] = [];
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
            $itemData = [];
            foreach ($item->getCustomAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $itemData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getValue();
            }
            $arrItems['items'][] = $itemData;
            $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();
        }
        //custom code//
        $currentUser=$this->getCurrentUserId();
        $seller_order_arr = [];
        foreach ($arrItems['items'] as $row) {
            if ($row['current_seller_id'] != null){
                if (in_array($currentUser, explode(",", $row['current_seller_id']))){
                    $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }
        $arrItems['items'] = $seller_order_arr;
        $arrItems['totalRecords']=$this->getTotalOrder($seller_order_arr);
        // end custom code//
        return $arrItems;

    }
```

These lines of code work perfectly order filter as i neend. But create problem for other grids. it can be solve by 2 way.

1 ) To put if() condition for custom code it should true if request come from Sales>Order and `false` if request come from other pages `invoice` or `shipment`  how can get order page `URL` for making codition.

2 ) Second is don't override the `generic` class . Try to filter order array an others way . In Which class::method we can filter orders array like i filter in`DataProvider` class.

Please guide me which is better in my case and how do that . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your main goal?

Comment: Actually i make multi vendor site. i filter orders as my code show every seller can view own product order. 
in the quest i upload code that filter. each seller see own order not others order

Comment: Your code has you overriding EVERY data provider. You rarely, if ever, need to override any data provider, certainly not everyone of them. Depending on which one it is, you can just add your ModifierInterface and do what you need with minimal intrusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per, my idea first one is not a good idea to override a class.

My suggestion to change the data provider the class of this grid
.

means changes  like

`<dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"`

to

```
<dataProvider class="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Ui\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"
```

that is the best process.

***Code of New UI Data provider class:***

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Ui\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider {

    protected function searchResultToOutput(\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface $searchResult) {
        $arrItems = [];
        $arrItems['items'] = [];
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
            $itemData = [];
            foreach ($item->getCustomAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $itemData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getValue();
            }
            $arrItems['items'][] = $itemData;
            $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();
        }
        //custom code//
        $currentUser = $this->getCurrentUserId();
        $seller_order_arr = [];
        foreach ($arrItems['items'] as $row) {
            if ($row['current_seller_id'] != null) {
                if (in_array($currentUser, explode(",", $row['current_seller_id']))) {
                    $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }
        $arrItems['items'] = $seller_order_arr;
        $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $this->getTotalOrder($seller_order_arr);
        // end custom code//
        return $arrItems;
    }

}
```

Also  override `sales_order_grid.xml` and past **datasource** tag in this file.

Comment: you mean to say override the `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`  file and give past this line `<dataProvider class="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Ui\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider` ?

Comment: Yes it work . i override `sales_order_grid.xml` and past `datasource` tag in this file.